# Laravel - prevent access to controller throug route in url

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a website based on Laravel. In my forms, I use routing to tell the form where to post my data, for instance route('login'), which could point to http://localhost:3000/login. However, if I manually write http://localhost:3000/login in the browser, I get a MethodNotAllowedHttpException which is fine, but how do I prevent the end user from seeing this exception and instead just returning him to the index page?

Answer (score 2):

You get a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` because your login route probably requires a `POST` request to get to the login view, and typing the URL directly is a `GET` request. You can redirect all `GET` requests to /login by adding this to `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::get('/login', function () {
    return redirect('/');
});
```

and you can replace `'/'` with whatever URL points to your index page.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a lot of features to make authentication easier, if you want to implement a login, this is what I do in all my developments, inside your project folder in the cmd just type:

- Run php artisan make:auth - This creates some controllers and views to manage authentication
- Run php artisan migrate - This creates the necessary tables in database

and now, you can refresh the site, and the authentication is done, you can get more information here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication,

if this is not what you want, I think the most reccomended for your case, could be a middleware, a middleware intercepts every request before to resolve it, so there you can make any validation that you want for every request,
again, to get more information about it, here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#terminable-middleware

Comment: This seems like a bloated comment. If you cut away all the excess what you end up suggesting is to use the authentication scaffolding or the middleware. I could be wrong. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

It's bad practice to redirect if that's the issue, you may take a look with this solution:

go to your **.env** file and add this code

```
  APP_ENV=production
  APP_DEBUG=false
```

and in

```
   resources/views/errors/405.blade.php
```

This will handle the error for **MethodNotAllowedHttpException** 
so of course you can customize the ui and message in that file.

Hope that helps!